# How to write a method returning an entity with either matched one attribute or partially matched another attribute?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

An entity class as

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
class Foo {
 ...
  private String symbol;
  private String name;
 ...
}
```

Now, I need to have a method of Spring Data JPA so that it takes one String parameter and it will return an entity if its `symbol` attribute matches the parameter. If there is not a matched symbol, it could return an entity if the name attribute partially matched the parameter. The order of search shall be the `symbol` first and then the `name`. I ask how to come up with a such method to someone who is an expert on the subject. After seven rounds, I don't have the right method. The method is something like the following.

```java
default Optional<Foo> findBySymbolOrName(String term) {
    Specification<Foo> spec = Specification.where(
        (root, query, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get("symbol"), term)
    );

    Optional<Foo> foo = findOne(spec);

    if (foo.isPresent()) {
        return foo;
    }

    spec = Specification.where(
        (root, query, cb) -> cb.like(root.get("name"), "%" + term + "%")
    );

    return findOne(spec);
}
```

For this version, the issue is about the `fineOne` method:

> Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound;
> should extend 'com.abc.domain.Foo'

If I replace `findOne` with

```java
Optional<Stock> findById(Specification<Foo> spec);
```

The IDE shows multiple errors

> Cannot resolve symbol 'FooRepository' in a class importing the
> repository and
>
> Cannot resolve method 'existsById(Long)'

in a class using the method. The repository is defined as

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> { ...}
```

How to have a correct method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your repository should, in addition to `JpaRepository`, extend [`JpaSpecificationExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html) which provides several methods for `Specification`s execution including the `Optional<T> findOne(Specification<T> spec)`.

```java
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Foo> { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. After adding the extension JpaSpecificationExecutor<Foo>, I get the second set of errors for some reason.

Comment: Not sure whether it is something messed up in my IDE or not.

Comment: What set of errors you got?

Comment: The second set, I mentioned in my post. Its client classes don't recognize it anymore. I can build the project outside of IntelliJ Idea. So, it is something wrong with Idea. I need to ask the Intellij about the error.

Comment: By the way, the solution was provided by ChatGPT. It missed mentioning the JpaSpecification extension. My post likely would get deleted if I didn't mention ChatGPT in my post.